# Update a Red Hat repo with no packages

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, repository

I'm attempting to install a handful of packages on my RHEL 5.10 (Tikanga) server, however I'm prevented from doing this because of an installed repo with zero packages.

When I do `yum repolist`, it shows up as this (other repos hidden):

```
 repo id       repo name                     status 
 zabbix        RS Zabbix Repository          0
```

I came across the answer in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109585/yum-update-fails-error-cannot-retrieve-repository-metadata-repomd-xml-for-re) however, I'd rather update it or restore the packages that it should have rather than delete or disable it.

How can I go about this? All searching points to systems that do not apply to me. Here is the output from `yum repolist -v zabbix`:

```
Loading "rhnplugin" plugin  Loading "security" plugin  Config time:
0.072 This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite. Looking for repo options for [main] Looking for repo options for [rhel-x86_64-server-5] Repo 'rhel-x86_64-server-5' setting option 'enabled' = '1' Repo 'rhel-x86_64-server-5' setting option 'gpgcheck' = '1' Looking for repo options for [rs-rhel-x86_64-server-5-common] Repo 'rs-rhel-x86_64-server-5-common' setting option 'enabled' = '1' Repo 'rs-rhel-x86_64-server-5-common' setting option 'gpgcheck'
= '1' Looking for repo options for [rhel-x86_64-server-vt-5] Repo 'rhel-x86_64-server-vt-5' setting option 'enabled' = '1' Repo 'rhel-x86_64-server-vt-5' setting option 'gpgcheck' = '1' Yum Version:
3.2.22 http://el5.racklabs.co.uk/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found Trying other mirror. Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: zabbix. Please verify its path and try again
```

Comment: Is this a local mirror of the repo, or are you trying to access the main zabbix repo?

Comment: @JennyD I'm not sure, is there a way to determine this? `yum info zabbix` doesn't return repo information.

Comment: `yum info` gives info about packages. `yum repolist -v zabbix` will show you the info about the repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL appears to be broken or incorrect for Zabbix.

```
$ curl -I http://el5.racklabs.co.uk/repodata/repomd.xml
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Trans-Id: tx22005d1372924371a082e-00530356f9lon3
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
Expires: Tue, 18 Feb 2014 12:50:31 GMT
Date: Tue, 18 Feb 2014 12:50:01 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Notice it's returning a 404? I'd double check to make sure you're installation is correct/current for that repo. Their main page for downloading a `.repo` file is here, titled: [3 Installation from packages](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/installation/install_from_packages).

Shows this command for EL5:

> #### Zabbix 2.0 for RHEL5:
>
> 64-bit
>
> ```
> $ sudo rpm -ivh http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/2.0/rhel/5/x86_64/zabbix-release-2.0-1.el5.noarch.rpm
> ```
>
> 32-bit
>
> ```
> $ sudo rpm -ivh http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/2.0/rhel/5/i386/zabbix-release-2.0-1.el5.noarch.rpm
> ```

The primary repo is also here: http://repo.zabbix.com/.

Comment: Many thanks for this. This did indeed resolve the problem for me, however it has trashed the original `RS Zabbix Repository`. I know have `Zabbix Official Repository - x86_64` under the repo id of `zabbix`.

Comment: @crmpicco - sorry, are you on x86-64 or i686? You can change the command around and get that architecture if needed. You can remove and re-install 32-bit if needed. I've added directions for installing it.